# Recuperar nome do volume da unidade de disco mapeada em rede

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sistema-de-arquivos, treeview

Estou usando `DriveInfo.GetDrivers()` para pegar os nomes das unidades de disco presentes na maquina e listar elas numa `TreeView`.

fiz o código abaixo que funciona, porem não aparece os nomes de discos em rede que minha maquina possui acesso, apenas os discos locais.

```
foreach(DriveInfo drv in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
    node.ImageIndex = 0;
    node.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
    node.Text = drv.Name+drv.VolumeLabel; 
    node.Nodes.Add("");
    treeview.Nodes.Add(node);
    retorno = true;
}
```

Quando eu concateno com o `drv.VolumeLabel` que os discos em rede param de aparecer (concateno para aparecer ao usuário o nome do disco para identificação)

Estou pensando num `if` para exibir eles, porem o objetivo era exibir o nome do disco em rede, pois grande parte do trabalho estarão em redes diferentes.

Atualização:

Fiz um `If` para exibir corretamente o nome do disco e exibir pelo menos a letra do dr*i*ve de rede

```
if (drv.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
   node.Text = drv.Name;
else if (drv.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
   node.Text = drv.Name + drv.VolumeLabel;
else
   node.Text = drv.Name;
```

e é exibido assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que nesse meio ai tem *pendrive* ligado, HD em rede e disco CD-Rom no meio.

Comment: Quando é um *drive* de rede, o `drv.VolumeLabel` tem conteúdo ou está nulo?

Comment: o Conteúdo do drv.VolumeLabel é "Dados".

Comment: E isso resolveu? Acho que era o que eu estava pensando.

Comment: Então, eu preciso mostrar ao usuário o nome do drive de rede, ao invés da letra, porquê são muitas letras, da uma olhada na imagem que eu vou colocar na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente o jeito de fazer isto é com WMI, segundo essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088905/221800). Faça o teste com este código para ver se retorna o que deseja e adapte ao que precisa.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_MappedLogicalDisk"); 
foreach (var queryObj in searcher.Get()) WriteLine("VolumeName: {0}", queryObj["VolumeName"]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetMappedDrives.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-mappedlogicaldisk?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Beleza cara, funcionou, valeu